# Java: How can I edit and adjust a variable in a text file?

Tags: java

I have a textfile called input.txt. I want to adjust the variable of price[cost] in that text file to lower the prices by a certain percentage, then output it. The code I've compiled so far doesn't work so I haven't even tried to output it. What can I do to fix it?

Note: I want to use an if structure as much as possible.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   import java.io.*;

   public class 111111 
   {
   public static String[] code = new String[1000];
   public static String[] desc = new String[1000];
   public static double[] price = new double[1000];
   public static double[] cost = new double[1000];
   public static double[] inv = new double[1000];
   public static double[] retailValue = new double[1000];
   public static double[] profitValue = new double[1000];

   public static int count = 0;
   public static int totalInv = 0;
   public static double totalRetail = 0.0;
   public static double totalProfit = 0.0;
   public static String[] adjustPrices1;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{   
    String fileName = "input.txt";
    FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader inputBuffer = new BufferedReader(inputFile); 

    String numString = inputBuffer.readLine();

    while (numString != null)
        if (price[count] < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Price cannot be negative, 
    please correct the mistake and restart the program.");
        }
        else if (price[count] < 10.00) 
            price[count] = price[count] * 0.95;

        else if (price[count] >= 10.00 && price[count] <= 99.99)
            price[count] = price[count] * 0.90;

        else if (price[count] >= 100.00 && price[count] <= 499.99)
            price[count] = price[count] * 0.80;

    else 
        price[count] = price[count] * 0.70;

    //Header
        String companyName = inputBuffer.readLine();
        System.out.println(companyName);
        System.out.printf("%-10s %-20s %10s %10s %10s %15s %15s \n", "Code", 
    "Description", "Price", "Cost", "Qty", "Retail Value", "Profit Value");

    //Body
        String numString = inputBuffer.readLine();
        while (numString != null)
        {
            String[] a = numString.split(",");
            code[count] = (a[0]).trim();
            desc[count] = (a[1]).trim();
            price[count] = Double.parseDouble((a[2]).trim());
            cost[count] = Double.parseDouble((a[3]).trim());
            inv[count] = Double.parseDouble((a[4]).trim());
            retailValue[count] = processInput(price[count], inv[count]);
            profitValue[count] = processInput(price[count], cost[count], 
    inv[count]);

            totalInv += inv[count];
            totalRetail += retailValue[count];
            totalProfit += profitValue[count];
            doOutput();
            count ++;
            numString = inputBuffer.readLine();
        }

            //Footer

            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------
    -------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("The total number of products read in was " + 
    count + ".");
            System.out.println("The total of inventory items read in were " + 
    totalInv + ".");
            System.out.printf("The total retail value of inventory is $%,.2f. 
    \n", totalRetail);
            System.out.printf("The total profit value of inventory is $%,.2f.     
    \n", totalProfit);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no variables in text file.

Comment: @Scott-Hunter I thought variable was the right word, my bad! Basically I just want to adjust the double price[cost] in a line like this: 

> JG06,Head First Design,500.00,450.00,1400 - where it goes code[count],desc[count],price[count],cost[count],inv[count].

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a proper description. What does it do and what do you expect it to do. Imagine calling your garage and saying "my car doesn't work, whats wrong?". What will be the first question you're asked?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is how you are reading your file. You need to read the file line by line, then set a variable to the number on that line.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       price[count] = Double.valueOf(line);
    }
}
```